# TypeError: string indices must be integers, in weather api when accessing dictionary key values

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, weather-api

I'm a beginner learning python, and am currently making a program that sends me a text every morning with the day's weather conditions. I am using the AccuWeather api, and the textbelt api for sending the text itself. Anyways, I have an empty list to append the weather data to, and then have a for loop that adds the certain dictionary key values from the api (here is that segment)

```
desc = []
day = []

for i in reqResp.text['DailyForecasts']:
    day.append(i['Temperature']['Minimum']['Value'])
    day.append(i['Temperature']['Maximum']['Value'])

for x in reqResp.text['Headline']:
    desc.append(x['Text'])
```

[Temp][min/max],etc are strings up until the [value] itself (which is an integer value). When I run the program, it states TypeError: String indices must be integers (starting at the line where the for loop starts.) Any help would be appreciated, as I am at a block.

Comment: Sounds like you're accessing the raw text of the response (a string), rather than the result of JSON decoding (which might include dictionaries with the keys you're mentioning).

Comment: as @jasonharper mentioned - you're using the reqResp.text which 99.99% is a string NOT a JSON / dictionary object; try instead a `json.loads` like this: `my_payload = json.loads(reqResp.text)` and from there parse `my_payload`

Comment: @jasonharper & @ Mache thank you both! i am sorry for my lack of skills, you both were very helpful, as both methods were able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
desc = []
day = []

for i in reqResp.json()['DailyForecasts']:
    day.append(i['Temperature']['Minimum']['Value'])
    day.append(i['Temperature']['Maximum']['Value'])

for x in reqResp.json()['Headline']:
    desc.append(x['Text'])
```

Comment: It is now only displaying the error for the "for x..." loop. Is this perhaps because 'Value' has an integer key value, and 'Text' has a string key value response?